# Significance of 1e8 in divisions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to understand a small function call in SQL Server 2012. I tried to search for it online but could not find much info.

The function itself is simple. It has two parameters @value and @default, both being int. This function `DivFix` returns @default when @value is null or 0, else it returns the @value itself.

This function is called in various SQL statements to avoid divide by zero error.

```
Select col1 / DivFix(col2,1e8)
```

My question is, what does 1e8 stand for here, and how does it help in overcoming the divide by zero error?

Comment: why not do a `SELECT 1e8` and see what you get? hint: it's `100000000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means 10^8 (10 power 8), thus 100000000. 
It's a short for "power(10, 8)"

From a mathematical point of view, it's not really a great way to handle "divide by 0" issue IMHO.

It would have more sense to use a very little number (which returns something close to infinite rather than a NaN / a failure) instead of this very big one (which makes the calculus return "something close to 0 but not exactly", unless the final rounding makes it equal to 0).

Comment: I think 0 is a far easier error case to deal with than 'something close to infinite', which I assume is the intent of whoever wrote that code.

Comment: Indeed, of course ! But in a "mathematical" sense it's not really accurate. It depends of the expected results/behavior. As long as everybody is aware of this, it's probably ok.

Answer (score 1):

`xEy` is a common short hand for `x * 10^y`. So `2e8 = 2 * 10^8`.

As to how it helps with divide by zero or null: I have no idea what your requirement is. `x/0` isn't a valid math operation. In calculus, the result can either be positive infinity of negative infinity, depending on how you approach 0.

The current intention seems to be make the result a very small number. So why not define a constant or just set the result to 0:

```
DECLARE @VerySmallNumber float = 1E-8 -- ha! the exponent can be negative too

SELECT IIF(col2 = 0 OR col2 IS NULL, @VerySmallNumber, col1 / col2)
```